# Changing TabIndex when a control gets disabled

Tags: c#, winforms, button, controls

In my c# winforms application, I have two buttons named  `left` and `right` which they go through some values.

When data reaches end, `right` button is getting disabled. As soon as `left` button is clicked `right` button gets enabled again and same for beggining of the data.

The problem is, If I reach the end and `right` is disabled, the TabIndex jumps to next control in the form. But I want it to jump to the pervious TabIndex which is the `left` button.

I have tried the `Focus()` Method. It works, but I literally want it like the user has pressed the TAB key to get there (I mean the dash line around the control).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `Select()` method. You can pass two arguments specifying whether a preceding or following control in tab order should be selected.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb97bya5.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First check whether right button is disabled or not.
If right button is disabled, then make the left button .focus()
Unless you post your sample code or something, it is difficult to answer more than this